# Angular Amplify init Cognito: Profile configuration is missing for default

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

After running the amplify init command in the root folder of my angular project I get the following error message when I dont want to create a new user:

```
init failed
Error: Profile configuration is missing for: default
    at Object.getProfiledAwsConfig (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\lib\system-config-manager.js:82:11)
    at getAwsConfig (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\lib\initializer.js:67:45)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\lib\initializer.js:44:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I already have an account with App ClientID and App Client Secret. I type in the accessKeyId, secretAccessKey and the region and then the error message appears.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Update
    ~/.aws/credentials (Linux & Mac) or %USERPROFILE%.aws\credentials (Windows)
and
    ~/.aws/config (Linux & Mac) or %USERPROFILE%.aws\config (Windows)
with the default options as described in the link below

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html